# creating multiple thread objects in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, nullpointerexception, thread-safety

How can i get rid of this problem. How to create multiple thread objects?

```
public void filterControl (int threadCount) {
    this.rowCount = img.getHeight() / threadCount;
    Thread[] t = null;

    for (int i=0; i<threadCount; i++) {
        t[i] = new Thread(new Runnable(){ //there is a NullPointerException

            @Override
            public void run() {
                filtering(startRow, rowCount);
            }
        });

        t[i].run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `NullPointerException` comes from the fact that you initialized your array as `null`.

Initialize it instead as:

```
Thread[] t = new Thread[threadCount];
```

This will initialize all its elements as `null` (the default value for `Object`s), but the array itself as a non-`null` instance, with a total of `threadCount` element slots.

**Note**

You do not start a `Thread` by invoking `run`, which will execute the `run` method within the invoking thread.

Use `t[i].start();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array before trying to use the "array".

Try replacing

```
Thread[] t = null;
```

to

```
Thread[] t = new Thread[threadCount];
```